# agent-state: pending for over 20 minutes

Tags: juju

I'm using juju against HP Cloud and the instance shows built and I can ping it fine but the juju status is showing it's still pending and it's not coming up in a browser.  Any ideas on what could cause this and how I can diagnose what's going on?

```
machines:
   "0":
     agent-state: started
     agent-version: 1.11.0
    dns-name: 15.185.97.43
    instance-id: "1569389"
     series: precise
   "1":
     instance-id: pending
     series: precise
     services:
   juju-gui:
     charm: cs:precise/juju-gui-61
     exposed: true
     units:
       juju-gui/0:
         agent-state: pending
         machine: "1"
```

Comment: I made some more machines and they all show pending an the instance-state shows "missing" so obviously I set something up wrong :(

Answer (score 2):

The current version of juju, 1.16.3 addresses a lot of the issues in 1.11.0 - if you haven't already tear down this install with `juju destroy-environment`, upgrade juju, then attempt to bootstrap again.

If that doesn't work, check your HP account if you have instances actually spun up. If not, consider destroying the environment again then `juju bootstrap --show-log --debug` to identify what's going on.